# How to create a contact in Outlook with Excel data?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel sheet that has a list of contact names, company names and email addresses.

I want to export these to Outlook.

I have done some code to delete current entries in a contact folder using VBA from Excel, but when adding a new contact, I am getting a 438 Runtime error.

Code to add a contact:

```vb
Sub addnewcontacts()
    Dim runoutlook As Outlook.Application
    Set runoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set findnamespace = runoutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set activefolder = findnamespace.Folders
    n = 1
    Do Until activefolder.Item(n) = "user@domain.co.uk"
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    Set myfolder = activefolder.Item(n)
    Set myfolder2 = myfolder.Folders("Contacts").Folders("CustGBP")
    lastrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Sheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
    Sheets("Sage Data").Activate
    If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then

        ' IT BREAKS AT THIS LINE
        Set olitem = myfolder2.CreateItem(olContactItem)

        With olitem
            .FullName = Trim(Range("A" & i).Value). 
            .Company = Trim(Range("B" & i).Value)
            .Email1Address = Range("G" & i).Value
        End With
        olitem.Save
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Working delete code:

```
Sub outlookdelete()
    Dim runoutlook As Outlook.Application
    Set runoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set findnamespace = runoutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set activefolder = findnamespace.Folders
    n = 1
    Do Until activefolder.Item(n) = "user@domain.co.uk"
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    Set myfolder = activefolder.Item(n)
    Set myfolder2 = myfolder.Folders("Contacts").Folders("CustGBP")
    Do
        For Each ContactItem In myfolder2.Items 
             ContactItem.Delete
        Next ContactItem

    ' this is in as otherwise it would only delete a handful
    '  each time it ran for some reason
    Loop Until myfolder2.Items.Count = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the item from the application itself (i.e. your `runoutlook` Outlook Object) and then move it to the desired folder. Starting at where you encounter the error, you can update your code with the following

```
// Creates a contact Item in the default Contacts folder
Set olitem = runoutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)
With olitem
    .FullName = Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)
    .Company = Trim(Range("B" & i).Value) ' may need to change to "CompanyName" 
    .Email1Address = Range("G" & i).Value
    .Move DestFldr:=myfolder2 // moves the contact to the indicated folder
    .Save
End With
```

As for the deletion of all the contacts, you can try this code instead

```
Do While myfolder2.Items.Count <> 0
    myfolder2.Items.Remove (1)
Loop
```

Comment: I ended up using a slightly different method, but this would also have worked fine. Another question I have is on some machines, in Outlook, the folder path starts with "User - ..." instead of "user@domain.com". Any ways I can get around that?

Comment: Added my code underneath here. Changed how the contact is added in my version and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get it working myself

```
For i = 1 To lastrow
Sheets("Data").Activate
If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
Set olitem = myfolder2.Items.Add(olContactItem)
With olitem
.FullName = Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)
.CompanyName = Trim(Range("B" & i).Value)
.Email1Address = Range("G" & i).Value
.Save
End With
End If
Application.StatusBar = "Updating Contacts: " & Format(i / lastrow, "Percent") & " Complete"
Next i
```